# Paypal recurring payments stopping

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I am using recurring payments in Paypal. And successfully implemented.

Now if the user choose another package, I need to start a new
recurring and stop current recurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send modify = 2, parameter with form where you are allowing user to modify plan.

Go to following link and search modify

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Comment: I have buttons with modify="2", which is what was shown in the PayPal docs.  However, the change isn't working.  Do you know if there is a different between modify="2" and modify=2?